# Hide few action bar items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have a base activity. I'm inflating the action bar items from base activity. Now in my Main Activity, which extends Base Activity, I'm replacing the fragments.So while replacing I'm hiding refresh icon and showing share icon. But share icon gets displayed before the 2nd fragment is loaded. once 2nd fragment is displayed, again share icon is hide, Why so..Here is what i tried.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mMenu = menu;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

private void showOption(int id) {
    MenuItem item = mMenu.findItem(id);
    item.setVisible(true);
}

private void hideOption(int id) {
    MenuItem item = mMenu.findItem(id);
    item.setVisible(false);
}
```

Methods for hiding and showing icons...

while replacing the fragment, I'm doing this :

```
replaceFragment(mDetailFragment);
            showOption(R.id.action_share);
            hideOption(R.id.action_refresh);
```

Comment: use setVisibiltiy(View.Gone) to hide

Comment: Can you add `invalidateOptionsMenu();` after `hideOption(R.id.action_refresh);` and see if it works?

Comment: Okay..I will try and let u know

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate through each menu item of your menu reference to change their property.

```
 Menu mMenu ;
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      mMenu = menu;
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

 private boolean changeVisibility(int menuId, boolean visibility) {
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        if (mMenu .getItem(i).getItemId() == menuId) {
            mMenu .getItem(i).setVisible(visibility);
        }
    }    
}
```

Then use it any where in the activity as :

```
replaceFragment(mDetailFragment);
changeVisibility(R.id.action_share, true);
changeVisibility(R.id.action_refresh, false);
```

Comment: But i need to replace the action bar items, while replacing the fragments..If i write this method inside activity, it will called in the beginning itself right?

Comment: Why we need to iterate it..Why it doesn't work, if we give directly..I know its silly..But I'm a beginner..so kindly cooperate

Comment: it is giving same result..first its displaying.But once the fragment becomes visible, its hidden

Comment: You are correct `mMenu.findItem(id)` should work, but it failed for me and the code `mMenu.getItem(i).getItemId()` worked on one of my activities. It is executed `onCreateOptionMenu()`.  I thought it might work for you. But I am not clear with ur last comment. Illiterate it a little.

Comment: I mean: I have 2 fragment..in my first fragment, only refresh icon is displayed. When i click on a item of list fragment, it should redirect me to detail fragment. When the detail fragment is about to load, share icon is showed, and once the fragment is filled with data, it becomes invisible..and again refresh button is shown